# Getting unused variable warning

Tags: c, arrays, gcc-warning

I'm trying to make a program that takes 3 integers as input, assigns the 3 integers into an array, and outputs them in ascending order. I don't know why my program is not working and it says

```
unused variable 'array[]'
```

and I don't know why. I thought that if it goes through the if statement it would create the array in a new order (the proper ascending order). But when I run it, it just outputs the 3 integers that I input in that order.

```
int main(){

    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);

    char array[] = {num1, num2, num3};

    int largestNum = numLarge(num1, num2, num3); //function gets largest number

    if (num3 == largestNum){

        if (num2 > num1){
            char array[] = {num1, num2, num3};
        }
        else{
            char array[] = {num2, num1, num3};
        }
    }
    else if (num2 == largestNum){

        if (num3 > num1){
            char array[] = {num1, num3, num2};
        }
        else{
            char array[] = {num3, num1, num2};
        }
    }
    else if (num1 == largestNum){

        if (num3 > num2){
            char array[] = {num2, num3, num1};
        }
        else{
            char array[] = {num3, num2, num1};
        }
    }


    printf("%d ", array[0]);
    printf("%d ", array[1]);
    printf("%d", array[2]);




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `char[]` array for this? You should be using a `int[]` array.

Comment: im not sure im kinda new to programming is there a better way?

Comment: I suppose you know what a variable is and what the word "unused" means. So what is not clear? We a reno debugging service. You should have read [ask].

Comment: You keep defining another `char array[] ` in block scope, leaving the first untouched.

Comment: yes but why is it unused

Comment: Because you didn't use it, you used the more local ones and discarded them when they go out of scope. They are *different* variables.

Comment: Remove unused variable and define your array in the main and then use it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I run it, it just outputs the 3 integers that I input in that order.

Here in your code, in each and every `if` and `else` blocks you are re-creating a local `array[]` whose scope is within the braces `{}` of that particular `if`/`else` block i.e, `if(condition){//scope only here}` and after the end of braces you'd be left with the initial `array` and hence your output is always as the original order.

**How to avoid it?**

Instead of recreating the `array` in each `if` and `else` block, try assigning `num1`,`num2` & `num3` appropriately

I mean instead of something like:

```
if (num3 == largestNum){

    if (num2 > num1){
        char array[] = {num1, num2, num3};
    }
    else{
        char array[] = {num2, num1, num3};
    }
```

do something like this:

```
if (num3 == largestNum){

    if (num2 > num1){
         array[0] = num1; 
         array[1] = num2;
         array[2] = num3;
         //you can avoid re-assigning here as there is no change of order
    }
    else{
         array[0] = num2; 
         array[1] = num1;
         array[2] = num3;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the if-else blocks, you are creating another variable that has the same name as your array defined in the outer scope, thus hiding it. All the changes you do are to the local array defined inside the if-else, and are not touching the one you want.

What you really want is:

```
int main(){

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int num3 = 0;

scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);

int array[] = {num1, num2, num3};

int largestNum = numLarge(num1, num2, num3); //function gets largest number

if (num3 == largestNum){

    if (num2 > num1){
        array[0] = num1;// This shoudl be num1 and so on.
        array[1] = num2;
        array[2] = num3;
    }
    else{
        array[0] = num2;
        array[1] = num1;
        array[2] = num3;
    }
}
else if (num2 == largestNum){

    if (num3 > num1){
        array[0] = num1;
        array[1] = num3;
        array[2] = num2;
    }
    else{
        array[0] = num3;
        array[1] = num1;
        array[2] = num2;
    }
}
else if (num1 == largestNum){

    if (num3 > num2){
        array[0] = num2;
        array[1] = num3;
        array[2] = num1;
    }
    else{
        array[0] = num3;
        array[1] = num2;
        array[2] = num1;
    }
}


printf("%d ", array[0]);
printf("%d ", array[1]);
printf("%d", array[2]);




return 0;
}
```